# How to find the quotient $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2+Y^2-Z^2\rangle$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties

I am asked to find the coordinate ring of the variety $Z(X^2+Y^2-Z^2)$ in $\mathbb C^3$.So,the question reduces to finding the quotient ring $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2+Y^2-Z^2\rangle$.But I do not find resemblance with any known ring so that I can use first isomorphism theorem.So,what should be a proper way of approaching such questions?

Comment: $\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2-z^2)$ is good enough in many contexts. Can you provide more context about where this problem came from? It might be that there are motivations present in the source that haven't made it in to your post yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomials
$$x=UV,\quad y=\frac{V^2-U^2}2,\quad z=\frac{U^2+V^2}2$$
generate a subring
$$\Bbb C[x,y,z]\subset\Bbb C[U,V]$$
isomorphic to $\Bbb C[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^2-Z^2).$

Comment: I cheated: I looked at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95699/386889).